# Python: Get attributes

Tags: python, xml

If I've got an xml-tag like this:

```
  <article n="1" translation="Year_1973_fr.xml:1">
```

How can I access the "translation"-Attribute?

It's no problem to access the "n"-attribute, I simply do the following:
s.attrib["n"]

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Does `s.attrib["translation"]` work?

Comment: Are you using any libraries? Have any code? Did you get any errors? As is this question is far too broad to answer well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.attrib["translation"]` works:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> data = '<article n="1" translation="Year_1973_fr.xml:1"/>'
>>> element = ET.fromstring(data)
>>> element.attrib
{'translation': 'Year_1973_fr.xml:1', 'n': '1'}
>>> element.attrib['translation']
'Year_1973_fr.xml:1'
```

Answer (score 1):

For example using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
html_doc = """
 <article n="1" translation="Year_1973_fr.xml:1">
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
print soup.article['translation']
Year_1973_fr.xml:1
```